# Magento free shipping shopping cart rule to be applied after discount

Tags: magento

I have a problem for which I cannot find a solution. I have a shopping cart rule to give a free shipping for order subtotal > $75. However if a discount code is used this rule is applied again despite the fact that the total amount of the order is less than $75. No taxes and other fees are in place. I want to give a free shipping only if they spend > $75. Any ideas how can I solve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I think it doesn't totally matter (see what I did there?) but version number would be good to know.

Comment: The live site is running CE 1.4.0.1 but it is also valid for 1.6.2 clean installation with sample database. To add some more info, we are using flat rate shipping - always the same $3.75. No single rule is stopping processing of the rest. I am adding something worth 76$, get a free shipping, then I am applying a 10% discount code and my Grand Total becomes less than $75, but I still get a free shipping. It is clear that Magento uses the Subtotal without the discount amount, but how can I use the discounted sub-total. Tried different things proposed in Mage forums, but without any success. Tks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right, the shopping cart rule only works with the cart subtotal, as does the freeshipping carrier model. Using a small rewrite it is possible to change the behavior of the freeshipping model.

First, deactivate your shopping cart rule that grants free shipping. Then go to `System > Configuration > Shipping Methods` and activate the free shipping carrier, giving it a "Minimum Order Amount" of 75$.

Next, we need to add the rewrite so the freeshipping model uses the discounted value instead of the subtotal.

Add a module My_Shipping, with the appropriate module registration file. Since you are asking on stackoverflow, I'll assume you are familiar with creating Magento modules. Then add the `My/Shipping/etc/config.xml` file with the following rewrite declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <models>
            <shipping>
                <rewrite>
                    <carrier_freeshipping>My_Shipping_Model_Freeshipping</carrier_freeshipping>
                </rewrite>
            </shipping>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

The only thing missing now is the rewritten carrier model. The following code implements the change you require:

```
class My_Shipping_Model_Freeshipping extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Freeshipping
{
    /**
     * Force the original free shipping class to use the discounted package value.
     *
     * The package_value_with_discount value already is in the base currency
     * even if there is no "base" in the property name, no need to convert it.
     *
     * @param Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request
     * @return Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result
     */
    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
    {
        $origBaseSubtotal = $request->getBaseSubtotalInclTax();
        $request->setBaseSubtotalInclTax($request->getPackageValueWithDiscount());
        $result = parent::collectRates($request);
        $request->setBaseSubtotalInclTax($origBaseSubtotal);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Thats it. Now, if the subtotal including discount is above 75$, the free shipping method is available. Otherwise the customer won't see it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice. It will work in general case, but in our case we already use the free shipping in the admin area for reships and its min amount is set to 0.00, as for all reships we create an order in the admin area worth 0.01 to 0.05 depending on the number of products. So I need to find another solution.

Comment: You can (almost) as easy create a freeshippingfrontend shipping carrier based on the freeshipping carrier. Only a little additional xml and code required. Need help?

Comment: Think I got the idea. Will create a module which extends the freeshipping one with all the configuration options in place and then in the XML will rewrite the carrier_freeshipping model with my own, but only in frontend, so that it will not affect the backend stuff.

Answer (score 2):

You can try follow class. This must rewrite model "Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Address". This adds the option "Subtotal with discount" to the condition options in sales rule management in the admin panel.

```
class YourCompany_SalesRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Address extends Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Address {

/**
 * (non-PHPdoc)
 * @see Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Address::loadAttributeOptions()
 */
public function loadAttributeOptions()
{
    parent::loadAttributeOptions();

    $attributes = $this->getAttributeOption();

    $attributes['base_subtotal_with_discount'] = Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Subtotal with discount');

    $this->setAttributeOption($attributes);

    return $this;
}


/**
 * (non-PHPdoc)
 * @see Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Address::getInputType()
 */
public function getInputType()
{
    if ($this->getAttribute() == 'base_subtotal_with_discount')
        return 'numeric';

    return parent::getInputType();
}


/**
 * Add field "base_subtotal_with_discount" to address.
 * It is need to validate the "base_subtotal_with_discount" attribute
 * 
 * @see Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule_Condition_Address::validate()
 */
public function validate(Varien_Object $address)
{
    $address->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount($address->getBaseSubtotal() + $address->getDiscountAmount());

    return parent::validate($address);
}
```

}

Comment: I am able to do this with `base_subtotal`. However when I try with `base_subtotal_with_discount`, the `salesrule` in admin does not really show anything. Where do I add `base_subtotal_with_discount`?

Comment: I had to edit the line `$address->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount($address->getBaseSubtotal() + $address->getDiscountAmount());` into `$address->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount($address->getQuote()->getBaseSubtotal() + $address->getQuote()->getDiscountAmount());`

Answer (score 1):

It's unfortunately a bug I have noticed. They calculate the subtotal based on the undiscounted value. A way you could go around this would be to set the "Stop processing rules" for your discount code rule.

Comment: Not sure I'd characterize this as a bug. Certainly would characterize as a chance to add a configuration setting.